# Have a ADFS fallback location

Tags: model-view-controller, adfs2.0, fallback

We currently have a webapplication in a datacenter (two webserververs behind a loadbalancer). For the login, the user is redirected to a ADFS server, which now becomes a single point of failure.

Is it possible to configure two adfs servers (both pointing to the same domain), but using a different FQDN (and in our case, on a different site)?

Simply adding more validIssuers doesn't seem to work.

I'd rather not use DNS round robin or similar, we'd just like to fallback to the secondary ADFS if the first fails (to respond) for any reason.

The fallback mentioned below isn't wat I mean ;)
[How to fallback authentication from ADFS to form-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083871/how-to-fallback-authentication-from-adfs-to-form-based)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup ADFS as a farm, load balancer, high availability.

Be careful though - the ADFS FQDN is derived from the SSL certificate.

Comment: That is the solution we have in the datacenter. Let me elaborate.. we have a datacenter where the webapplication is running. We also have two (geographicaly seperated) locations, which run the same Active Directory. I'd like to run a ADFS server on each location, so that if the internet connection of one of the sites breaks, (remote) users still are able to login using the other ADFS server.